# calling pom from build.gradle

Tags: gradle, pom.xml

I have an existing pom.xml which I want my build.gradle should call while running gradle build. The pom.xml and build.gradle are at the same location. Which gradle task can help me doing this?

Answer (score 2):

```
task runMavenBuild(type: Exec) {
    executable = "mvn" // must reside on PATH
    args "install"
}
```

Comment: This gives me error: > A problem occurred starting process 'command 'mvn''
My PATH has maven set into it though: echo $PATH
/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/gnu/bin:/usr/dt/bin:/usr/openwin/bin:/opt/gnome/bin:/opt/local/etc:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/atria/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/quest/bin:/opt/local/dev_tools/java/latest-1.6:/opt/local/dev_tools/maven/apache-maven-3.2.1